# How to change the gradient for the color of the hovered part of the text when the user hovers over the letter of the phrase

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  const halfCircleSize = circle.offsetHeight / 2;

  const mouse_x = e.clientX;
  const mouse_y = e.clientY;

  circle.style.left = `${mouse_x - halfCircleSize}px`;
  circle.style.top = `${mouse_y - halfCircleSize}px`;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  background-color: #15140c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

* {
    cursor: grabbing;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
}

* ::selection {
    background: none;
}

span {
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

span.filled-text {
  z-index: 0;
  /* this */
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 33, 44, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

span.outlined-text {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  /* this */
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 33, 44, 0.8) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

#circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: calc(50vh - 100px);
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
}
```

```html
<span class="filled-text">
            <h1 data-text="Get to know more about">Get to know more about</h1>
          </span>
<span class="outlined-text" aria-hidden="true">
            <h1 data-text="Get to know more about">Get to know more about</h1>
          </span>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

In a project I'm working on, I need to use a special hover mode in the title section. In this way, in normal mode and when the user has not hovered over the title, the filled-text color should be `background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 33, 44, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%)`;.

When the user hovers over the title, the gradient should become a little lighter in the `circle(100px*100px)`. and change its gradient to `background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(26, 33, 44, 0.8) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%)`;

I have two problems with this code:
1- I don't want to use `-webkit-text-stroke` in this case. But if I remove it, nothing is displayed inside the circle during hover.

2-Create a gradient in `filled-text` and `outlined-text`:
When I have to use `color: transparent;` I put it, `background: linear-gradient` is not created

In general, I want the `background: linear-gradient` inside the circle to be a little lighter when the user hovers over this text.

Thank you for your help, what is the problem with my codes, thank you very much Or if you have a sample, introduce it to me